# Why I get Error 404 trying to get an image from Node server?

Tags: node.js, image, express

I have some images saved in the server folder `assets/img/products/`

In the file `server.js` I make the `products` folder public:

```
app.use(express.static('./assets/img/products'));
```

but if I use the link: `http://localhost:3000/assets/img/products/111_#1.jpg`
i get:

```
{"status":404,"message":"Not found"}
```

here my server folders:

```
- server
  server.js
  - assets
    - img
      - products
        111_#1.jpg
```

some ideas ??
THX

Comment: You just don't provide complete path in the url, it's http://localhost:3000/filename.jpg.

Comment: @wiktor Zychla I get the same error ...

Comment: the problem seems to be the # in the name of the image

Comment: Yes it is. Everything after the # is called an uri fragment and is not transmitted to the server.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla if you text a complete answer about it I can mark it like the best answer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Wiktor Zychla 's comment.

Directly copy pasted from [ExpressJS Website](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

> the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process. If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Maybe your path is incorrect? Please check it and don't forget to use `path.join`

Answer (score 0):

send image name in params and make path to that image in api like below

```
 let image_name = req.params.image_name

 let directory_name =`path/to/image/where/is/image/stored/${image_name}`

  // read the image using fs and send the image content back in the response
        fs.readFile(directory_name, function (err, content) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(400)
                console.log(err);
                res.end("No such image");
            } else {
                //specify the content type in the response will be an image
                res.writeHead(200);
                res.end(content);
            }
        });
```